# Mutating a list of strings to include K-means cluster number in R

Tags: r, dplyr, k-means

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@SAPCAI/text-clustering-with-r-an-introduction-for-data-scientists-c406e7454e76) and this is all super new to me, so apologies if it's an obvious question.

Following the tutorial, I have converted a list of strings, `sentences`, into a K-Means model with 4 clusters using the following:

```
corpus = tm::Corpus(tm::VectorSource(sentences)) 
tdm <- tm::DocumentTermMatrix(corpus.cleaned) 
tdm.tfidf <- tm::weightTfIdf(tdm)
tdm.tfidf <- tm::removeSparseTerms(tdm.tfidf, 0.999) 
tfidf.matrix <- as.matrix(tdm.tfidf) 
dist.matrix = proxy::dist(tfidf.matrix, method = "cosine")
model <- kmeans(dist.matrix, centers = 4)
```

Now, I would like to go back to the original list of `sentences` and show next to each one which cluster it forms part of. For example:

| sentences | cluster |
| --- | --- |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | 1 |
| Consectetur adipiscing elit | 2 |

I've tried the following (using the dplyr package):

```
clustered <- mutate(sentences, cluster = model$cluster)
```

and

```
clustered <- mutate(df$sentences, cluster = model$cluster)
```

But obviously this doesn't work, because as R says, "no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without data to test it, if I got it right, `sentences` is a list of strings, which you can use to create a column in a new dataframe, and `model$cluster` is an array where every position/index is related to the same one from the input. So, if the order of the list was kept, they are related. If this is true (I don't know because I never used `tm` library) you can just create a new dataframe with the list and the array.

```
kmeans_results = data.frame(
  sentence = sentences,
  clusterID = model$cluster
)
```

Comment: You are a genius. So simple and worked perfectly. I was making it much harder than it was. Thanks.

Comment: @FPL Be aware that this solution is only true if the distance matrix used in the Kmeans algorithm kept exactly the same order that the list of sentences. and you should check that before applying. That means: the rows/cols are symmetric and they follow the same order that the list `sentences`.

Comment: thanks, good point.

By the way, I noticed a small mistake in the solution (extra comma). The working code is:

kmeans_results = data.frame(
  sentence = sentences,
  clusterID = model$cluster
)

Comment: Totally right. Edited.